# virtual CPU in KVM

Tags: linux, kvm

Does anybody know, where vcpu thread id is stored in linux? In fact according to my researches when we create a VM in KVM, some threads will shape vcpus; i need the ID and location of them.
I took a look at this position:

/proc/`qemu-kvm process ID`/tasks/*/

the `qemu-kvm process ID` field comes from this location:
/var/run/libvirt/qemu/VM_NAME.xml

BECAUSE i thought that maybe vcpu's ID could be found there, but unfortunately they are not vcpu's ID, they are just some child process.

any help would be appreciated.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you exec qemu with parameters -qmp unix:./qmp-sock,server,nowait, for example:

```
# /opt/qemu/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -smp cpus=2 \
    -drive file=/opt/test.qcow2,format=qcow2 \
    -cdrom CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1511.iso \
    -qmp unix:./qmp-sock,server,nowait
```

You can exec qmp-shell to get cpu info:

```
# /opt/git/qemu/scripts/qmp/qmp-shell /opt/qmp-sock   
Welcome to the QMP low-level shell!
Connected to QEMU 2.5.50

(QEMU) query-cpus
{"return": [{"halted": false, "pc": -2124176787, "current": true, "qom_path": "/machine/unattached/device[0]", "thread_id": 2344, "arch": "x86", "CPU": 0}, {"halted": true, "pc": -2130342250, "current": false, "qom_path": "/machine/unattached/device[3]", "thread_id": 2341, "arch": "x86", "CPU": 1}]}
```

Thread id here: 2344 and 2341

```
# ps -eLf|grep qemu-system
root      2341  2252  2341  9    4 08:52 pts/0    00:00:48 /opt/qemu/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -smp cpus=2 -drive file=/opt/test.qcow2,format=qcow2 -cdrom CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1511.iso -qmp unix:./qmp-sock,server,nowait
root      2341  2252  2342  0    4 08:52 pts/0    00:00:00 /opt/qemu/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -smp cpus=2 -drive file=/opt/test.qcow2,format=qcow2 -cdrom CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1511.iso -qmp unix:./qmp-sock,server,nowait
root      2341  2252  2344 85    4 08:52 pts/0    00:07:04 /opt/qemu/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -smp cpus=2 -drive file=/opt/test.qcow2,format=qcow2 -cdrom CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1511.iso -qmp unix:./qmp-sock,server,nowait
root      2341  2252  2345  0    4 08:52 pts/0    00:00:00 /opt/qemu/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -smp cpus=2 -drive file=/opt/test.qcow2,format=qcow2 -cdrom CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1511.iso -qmp unix:./qmp-sock,server,nowait
root      2378  2304  2378  0    1 09:01 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto qemu-system
```

For more information see http://wiki.qemu.org/QMP

Answer (score 1):

I think vcpu thread ID is internal to Qemu and it is exposed to linux as a normal thread

```
struct CPUState {
...
struct QemuThread *thread;
...
int thread_id;
...
bool thread_kicked;
...
bool throttle_thread_scheduled;
...
};
```

You can use Qemu command `info cpus` to show information about cpus. It gives me this:

```
(qemu) info cpus
* CPU #0: pc=0x00000000b483c8c4 thread_id=6660
```

Comment: thank you Yachine, I have a Q, where those lines of code come from in your above answer? further `(qemu) info cpus` does not work in my system. Do you know what may be going wrong?